# Discord.js MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: discord.js

I'm getting this error:

> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be
> non-empty strings.

This is my code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client | ✅')

    command(client, 'ping', (message) => {
        let x = `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + 'ms'
        console.log(x)
        const embedval = x
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(' Pong!')
            .addField(x)

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

[`<MessageEmbed>.addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) method take two arguments, a name and a value, you specified the name `x` but not the value, example to fix your error:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .addField('Ms: ', x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Client | ✅')

command(client, 'ping', (message) => {
    let x = `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + 'ms'
    console.log(x)
    const embedval = x
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(' Pong!')
        .addField('Ms:', embedval)

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
})
})
```